# Find the limit of $x_{n+1} = 4 - \frac{1}{x_n}$, given that it is convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I already have that it is bounded above and below by 3,4 and have proven it. I just do not know how to verify that 4 is definitely the limit. Is it being bounded enough to justify the claim and if not how do I go about proving it?

Comment: $4$ is not the limit.  When is $x_{n+1}-x_n$ positive and when negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it converges, then $X=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, and

$$X=4-\frac1X\implies X^2-4X+1=0\implies X=2\pm\sqrt3$$

Since $3\le X\le4$, we have

$$X=2+\sqrt3$$

Comment: It is enough to invoke the Banach fixed point theorem, since the derivative of $4-\frac{1}{x}$ in a neighbourhood of $2+\sqrt{3}$ is pretty small in absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Call $x$ the limit.

Then, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = x$$

Now, what is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[4-\frac1{x_n}\right]$$
 equal to?

Answer (score 1):

If the limit exists, one index shift will make little difference; so treat $$x_{n+1}=x_{n}=L$$
And solve 
$$
L=4-1/L
$$